# Switching among theme customizations

Tags: themes, database, child-theme, theme-options

I am developing a website that should switch between two looks (depending on the season) using different customizations of one WordPress theme. I mean all the changes are done on the `wp-admin/customize.php` page, without touching files, switching plugins, etc.

I started to write down changes needed to switch the versions (e.g. disable the secondary menu, switch header image, adjust positioning, …). As the list grows, I started to wonder if there is a way to keep both versions stored in WordPress and switch them at once. I am thinking about duplicating my child theme and store each customization in one of them. However, these themes would contain identical files and only differ in the customization which is stored in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'theme_mods_%';
```

I guess I could switch the customizations directly in the database by changing the `option_name` (haven’t tried it yet though) but I’d like to do it more user-friendly, so I wonder:

**Is there any way, e.g. a plugin, to switch among multiple saved customizations of the same theme (without tampering with the database)?**

I tried to google this topic but unfortunately, I only got a ton of results about switching WordPress themes…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found this to be possible using the [Customizer Export/Import](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/) plugin.